# Remove froward slash after file name using htaccess file & Redirect to 404 page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, seo

My site URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/about.php
```

This link open about.php file contain. If we try with below link

```
http://www.example.com/about.php/images/css/style.css
```

This link also open my about.php file contain ( this type of 20k url generate automatically and open about.php file contain ). This error in SEO toll

Eg .

```
1) http://example.com/about.php/images/css/style.css
2) http://example.com/about.php/images/js/script.js 
.
.
   http://example.com/about.php/anything
```

above URL generate auto and that show about.php file contain.
How i redirect this URL's to 404 page

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add the current content of your .htaccess file?

Comment: i don't have .htaccess file

Comment: Then how are your URL's going through about.php to begin with? Or are you typing those?

Comment: No, My Problem is http://www.domain.com/about.php/images/css/style.css  this url open my about.php file contain.

This issue find SEO guys

Comment: If I get that right, I would rather take a look at how your Webserver loads PHP. If the Webserver just calls PHP if the request ends with `.php`, you should update it!

Comment: @SimonSimCity How i check my webserver

Comment: @PanjabShelke, the question is more, what webserver do you have ... I guess it's one of this list: nginx, Apache, IIS, lighttp.

I know, that this problem exists in nginx (http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample) but have not much knowledge about the rest of them.

Comment: @PanjabShelke You can find out what server you have by calling `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and in it's result, searching for `_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]`

Comment: @SimonSimCity i have apache

Comment: @PanjabShelke Sorry, I don't know how that's done in Apache. Maybe the keyword `PATH_INFO` does help you here ...

Comment: @SimonSimCity can we restrict this from .htaccess file

Comment: @PanjabShelke Think so, but I would not rely on that to make your environment safe.
How do you know, that it's the filename? Just because the fragment `about.php` has a dot? Do you (on forehand) know, that a dot in a name implies, that this is a filename? For Apache, this is just a string. It doesn't know what is a file or what is a directory. You will have to make a lot of assumptions here, that will limit you in what you can do and what not, if you don't get the problem properly solved.

Comment: @PanjabShelke but does a request for `../about.php/images/css/style.css` return the plain php file (the code) or just the website? If it's the website, it's fine. Search-engines have no trouble with that. You may provide canonical-tags to make it sure. But if it's the php code, it's a security-vulnerability that should be fixed asap.

Comment: @SimonSimCity No, its open about.php file contain. but generate dynamic urls like "domain.com/about.php/images/photo.jpg"(this also open about.php file contain ). its create problem for SEO

Comment: @SimonSimCity i want to restrict user to open "domain.com/about.php/images/photo.jpg" this type of url and redirect this type of url to 404 page

only user can open "domain.com/about.php" page

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller, Hey u change my complete question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solve my problem with regular expression below is my code for .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.php\/ http://example.com/error-page.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your web server or your *.htaccess* file.  You need to change your index.php file to generate non-broken links.

Instead of linking to

```
../about.php/images/css/style.css
```

Your index.php file should link to

```
/images/css/style.css
```

Then the URL for the CSS file will be correct:

```
http://example.com/images/css/style.css
```

You just need to edit the index.php file to make this change.

Comment: Hey u change my complete question

Comment: I tried to edit it for formatting, clarity and grammar while preserving your original meaning.   I apologize for anything I changed inappropriately.   Please edit it again to fix anything I got wrong.